# Check if string is member of Union type

Tags: typescript

To avoid type casting, I would like to learn when it's possible to safely determine the type of given values. I can do this with string enums like this:

```
enum Category {
    circle = "circle",
    square = "square",
}

const isObjValue = (val: any, obj: any) => Object.values(obj).includes(val)

isObjValue('circle', Category) // true
```

But how would I do it with string Unions?

```
const Category = "circle" | "square"

const isValidCategory = (string) => {
  if (/* string is in Category */) {
    return string as Category
  }
}
```

Still learning TS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dynamic value, you can create a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), to narrow the type of that value.

```
type Category = "circle" | "square"

// User-defined type guard that narrows the s from string type
// to Category type if s is either "circle" or "square".
function isCategory(s: string): s is Category {
    return s === "circle" || s === "square"
}

const a: string = "some dynamic string"
if (isCategory(a)) {
    // a type here is Category
    console.log(a, "is Category")
} else {
    // a type here is string
    console.log(a, "is not Category")
}
```

Comment: I was afraid it would involve this much typing (no pun)

Comment: You could create the Category type from an array and also use that array with the method `.includes()` in the `isCategory` function. But if you don't have a bunch of values, I think it just makes it more complex... Prefer simple, readable code over complex and concise.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to remember to always update both the type and "is" check function, you can instead use an array and have TS convert it to a union:

```
const ALL_CATEGORIES = ["circle", "square"] as const;
type typedCategoryList = typeof ALL_CATEGORIES;
type Category = typedCategoryList[number]; // this compiles to 'circle' | 'square'

const isCategory = (value: string) : value is Category => {
   return ALL_CATEGORIES.includes(value as Category )
}
```